# Migrating resuable modal from angularjs to Angular 14

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular14

I am migrating my application from Angularjs 1.X to Angular 14 and encountered an issue related to reusable modal popup (this is modal which shows the message with ok/cancel button in it).
Below is the Angularjs code written in controller ,

```
$rootScope.showConfirmModal = function (message, callback) {
        var modalHtml = '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Warning!</h3></div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body">' + message + '</div>';
        modalHtml += '<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>' +
            '<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button></div>';

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: modalHtml,
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                    callback(true);
                };

                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    callback(false);
                };
            }
        });
    }
```

The above modal popup has been called in most of the places in angularjs 1.x application.
Now how to move this into Angular 14.

Please help or suggest me with any example code, not sure whether to write as component or directive.

Comment: Create component for displaying modal window. Add also own service which sets when modal window is displayed.

Comment: @AvgustinTomsic i too had the same thought, but where to add this modal window (do i need to add the ng-template reference). Do you have any code reference?

Answer (score -2):

Here is similar example. Create the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDialogService } from './modal-dialog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-dialog',
  templateUrl: './modal-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-dialog.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalDialogComponent {
  config: any = null;
  constructor(private modalDialogService: ModalDialogService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.config = null;
    this.modalDialogService.show = this.show.bind(this);
  }

  show(config: any) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  onConfirm() {
    if (this.config && this.config.onConfirm) {
      this.config.onConfirm();
    }
    this.config = null;
  }

  onCancel() {
    if (this.config && this.config.onCancel) {
      this.config.onCancel();
    }
    this.config = null;
  }
}
```

with HTML:

```
<div class="modal-dialog fk-modal-dismissable" *ngIf="config">
  <div class="modal-dialog-wrapper">
    <div class="modal-dialog-header-wrapper">
      <span class="modal-dialog-header-text" *ngIf="config.headerText">
        {{ config.headerText }}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog-body-wrapper">
      <span class="modal-dialog-body-text">
        {{ config.bodyText || 'Are you sure?' }}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog-action-wrapper">
      <button class="btn2 modal-dialog-action" (click)="onCancel()">
        {{ config.cancelText || 'Cancel' }}
      </button>

      <button class="btn2 modal-dialog-action" (click)="onConfirm()">
        {{ config.confirmText || 'Confirm' }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use service to show popup:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalDialogService {
    constructor() {

    }
    show(config: any) {
        // implementation of function is declared in modal dialog component 
    }
}
```

Use component on app main html page, to make it work all routes.

Full working example is available here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4qzkh7?file=src/app/modal-dialog.service.ts

Running app:
https://angular-ivy-4qzkh7.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thanks @AvgustinTomsic for your answer, i created a modal without required to add the place holder like the component (<app-dialog></app-dialog>)